# How to know if sql service pack has been removed

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am new to the environment and we need to know if SQL 2008 R2 SP has been removed or it has never installed. is there any way to know such information ?

Comment: You can check in the registry.

Answer (score 1):

To see what is installed, execute `select @@version`, it should tell you build number and possibly the service pack, if it exists.  then cross-check it with the version release.  [How to determine the version and edition...](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321185)

To understand if something has been removed, best to check windows event log, or possibly the setup log folder, and dig through the logs to see what has happened.